# Does ${\rm e}^X$ is a random variable $\Rightarrow X$ is a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Does ${\rm e}^X$ is a random variable $\Rightarrow X$ is a random variable?

I know that if $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g$ is measurable, then $f\circ g$ is measurable.

But $f=\ln$ is only continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$, so I am not sure if I can use the statement above to show that $X=\ln{\rm e}^X=f\circ{\rm e}^X$ is random variable.

Is there another way to prove it or is there a counterexample showing this implication doesn't hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with that. If you are not sure you can do it very formally. Let $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open set. Let $f(x)=\ln(x)$. Then:

$\{X\in O\}=\{\ln(e^X)\in O\}=\{f(e^X)\in O\}=\{e^X\in f^{-1}(O)\}$

Since $O$ is open and $f$ is continuous we know that $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $(0,\infty)$, and since $(0,\infty)$ is an open set we get that $f^{-1}(O)$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable. And since $e^X$ is a random variable we conclude that $\{X\in O\}=\{e^X\in f^{-1}(O)\}$ is a measurable set as well. Since this is true for all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, it is true for all Borel sets. Hence $X$ is a random variable.

Comment: No, that's not a problem since $[0,\infty)$ is also a measurable set. The problem will come much earlier as the equality $\{X\in O\}=\{\sqrt{X^2}\in O\}$ is not true. $x^2$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,\infty)$ is not invertible.

Comment: Well, if $X$ is non negative then I guess a similar argument can be used. In that specific case indeed $\{X\in O\}=\{X\in O\cap [0,\infty)\}=\{\sqrt{X^2}\in O\cap [0,\infty)\}$, and then you can continue in a similar way.